# SharePoint 2019 Standard vs. Enterprise, Updates / Release / Patch / Versions and the SharePoint Framework Releases

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-administration

We have an SP2019 test farm running SharePoint Server 2019 Standard, version 16.0.10351.20000 (October 2019). I have a few questions regarding compatibility between SPFX development and SP2019 on-premise:

1. Is it important to keep the SP2019 environment updated with the latest monthly release in order to ensure compatibility with the latest version of the SharePoint Framework?
2. Is there any guidance regarding development targeting SP2019 standard edition vs. enterprise (article, blog post)?
3. Some on-line posts state that SPFX should be kept at version 1.4.1 for SP2019. Is this still true?
4. Does anyone have any experience regarding possible deployment issues when development is performed on SharePoint Online? Development environment is O365.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The SharePoint Framework in SharePoint Server 2019 will always be v1.4.1. No features will be added nor changed to SPFx. There may be some bugfixes to SPFx, but it will not change the framework version. With that said, the guidance is to keep SharePoint farms updated on a month-to-month basis with Microsoft updates.

If you want to keep your solution SharePoint Server 2019 compatible, you need to target SPFx to use SharePoint Server 2019 when creating your solution.

As far as development of Standard vs. Enterprise, the only key here is to not target Enterprise features. Those feature differences are outlined [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-service-description?redirectedfrom=MSDN#bkmk_FeaturesOnPremise), but note that they're marked SharePoint 2016 rather than 2019 (nothing has changed from a feature licensing perspective so it's still valid).

Comment: Thank you very much! That was very helpful.